# no 'void StringSet::removeALL()' member functions declared in class 'StringSet'

Tags: c++, function, linked-list

I have already checked other similar questions but I still can't get rid of the problem. I have tried to have the function both as public and private.

I have a functions removeALL in my class:

**Class decleration**

```
#ifndef STRINGSET_H
#define STRINGSET_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "StringNode.h"
using namespace std;

class StringSet
{
    public:
        // Constructor: creates an empty set.
        StringSet();

        // Destructor.
        ~StringSet();

        // Returns the number of elements in the set.
        int size();

        // Inserts 'element' into the set. If 'element' is contained in the
        // set, this operation has no effect.
        void insert(string element);

        // Removes 'element' from the set. If 'element' is not in the set, this
        // operation has no effect.
        void remove(string element);

        // Returns true if and only if 'element' is a member of the set.
        bool contains(string element);



        // A friend function for writing the contents of the set to an output stream.
        friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& outs, const StringSet& set);



    private:
        void removeAll();
        int fixing (string element);

        NodePtr head; // pointer to the head of the linked list
};

#endif // STRINGSET_H
```

But when i try to create the function in the cpp file I get the error: no 'void StringSet::removeALL()' member functions declared in class 'StringSet'

**RemoveALL function and header in cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "StringSet.h"

using namespace std;

void StringSet::removeALL()
{
     if(head == NULL){
        cout << "The list is empty" << endl;
        return;
    }

    while (NodePtr temp = head)
    {
        head = temp->getLink();
        delete temp;
    }

}

int StringSet::fixing(string element)
{
    int temp = 0;

    if(((element[0] == 'n') || (element[0] == 'N')) && ((element[1] == 'o') || (element[1] == 'O'))
       && ((element[2] == 't') || (element[2] == 'T')))
    {
        element.erase(0,3);
        remove(element);
        element.clear();
        temp = 1;
        return temp;

    }
    else return temp;
}
```

Does anyone have a solution?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ is case-sensitive. `removeAll` and `removeALL` are different things.